# Converting string with new lines into json array

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x

I have the following string(with new lines after each value):
"
value1
value2
value3
"
I need to convert it to a json array(using python) in the following format:

```
{"keywords": [{"keyword": "value1"},{"keyword": "value2"},{"keyword": "value3"}]}
```

I tried all kinds of methods, always resulting in invalid json.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string into an array, map it to a dictionary of `keyword:line`, and convert it into json.

```
import json

def map_line(line):
    return {"keyword": line}
    
lines = "value1\nvalue2\nvalue3".split("\n")
    
result = json.dumps({"keywords": list(map(map_line, lines))})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
sample_data = '{"keywords": [{"keyword": "value1"},{"keyword": "value2"},{"keyword": "value3"}]}'
for idx, key in enumerate(json.loads(sample_data)):
    for idx2, key2 in enumerate(json.loads(sample_data)[key]):
        print(key2)
```

Output:

```
{'keyword': 'value1'}
{'keyword': 'value2'}
{'keyword': 'value3'}
```